# Pylab plotfile() skips the first row of a file with no header - how to stop this?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been using [matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plotfile#matplotlib.pyplot.plotfilematplotlib.pyplot.plotfile) to plot some x,y values directly from a file. However, the first data row is being omitted from the plot.

I assume plotfile is treating the first row as a header row. Is there a way to stop this?

The only reference to header interpretation I have found is in the plotfile documentation (linked above), however I am passing the column indexes as an integer tuple like in the statement below:

```
plotfile(os.path.join(pathname,'foo.csv'), cols=(3,5), skiprows=0, delimiter=',', label='Series')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly name the columns using `names` keyword argument. For example:

```
plotfile(os.path.join(pathname,'foo.csv'), names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], cols=(3,5), skiprows=0, delimiter=',', label='Series')
```

According to [`csv2rec`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec) (which is used by `plotfile`):

> If names is None, a header row is required to automatically assign the
>   recarray names. The headers will be lower cased, spaces will be
>   converted to underscores, and illegal attribute name characters
>   removed. If names is not None, it is a sequence of names to use for
>   the column names. In this case, it is assumed there is no header row.

Comment: This worked for me, though the arbitrary column names do look a bit out of place in my code ;) Thanks!

Comment: @falsetru Is it possible to skip rows periodically with plotfile()?e.g. skip every row except for every 6th row!?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi, I'm not sure whether such option is provided. How about ask a separated question?

Comment: @falsetru thanks, I somehow solved the problem. Unfortunately I'm banned from asking questions for a week Since my questions weren't "well-perceived"

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with your parameter skiprows=0, isn't it?.
Or you can start your file from row 1.

I use this command and it's okay, did you try your file with names? Or command without parameters?

```
plotfile(data, (0,1,2),delimiter=";", marker = "x", markeredgecolor="r")
```

Comment: I did previously try it with and without skiprows=0, but this seemed to have no effect. What do you mean by "command without parameters"?